# CUDA: PRNG generator and state

Tags: random, cuda

I have been playing around with cuRAND library to understand the concept of a generator and state. The term `state` has yet puzzled me so I would like to clarify my understanding with the help of some code.

```
int main () {

float *hData, *dData;
curandState *devState;

size_t nThreads = 4;
size_t nRows    = 10;
size_t n        = nRows * nThreads;

hData = new float[n];
cudaMalloc((void**)&dData, n * sizeof(float));
cudaMemset(dData, 0, n * sizeof(float));

cudaMalloc((void**)&devState, nThreads * sizeof(curandState));
initCurand <<< 1, nThreads >>> (devState, 1234);
cudaDeviceSynchronize();

testrand <<< 1, nThreads >>> (devState, dData, nRows);
cudaDeviceSynchronize();
cudaMemcpy(hData, dData, n*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

cudaFree(devState);
cudaFree(dData);
free(hData);
}
```

Below are the kernels.

```
__global__ void initCurand(curandState *state, unsigned long seed)
{
    curand_init(seed, threadIdx.x, 0, &state[threadIdx.x]);
}

__global__ void testrand(curandState *state, float *d1, int rows)
{

    int idx    = threadIdx.x;
    int stride = blockDim.x;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        d1[idx + i * stride] = curand_uniform(&state[idx]);
    }
}
```

Simply put, there are as many states as the number of threads. Each thread consume 10 random numbers from THEIR respective state. Here is the output:

```
0.145468 0.820181 0.550399 0.294830 
0.434899 0.926417 0.811845 0.308556 
0.870710 0.511765 0.782640 0.620706 
0.455165 0.537594 0.742539 0.535606 
0.857093 0.809246 0.541354 0.497212 
0.582418 0.017524 0.195556 0.898062 
0.201404 0.449338 0.006050 0.041652 
0.786745 0.799349 0.093755 0.994597 
0.300772 0.136307 0.648018 0.970036 
0.366787 0.377424 0.096621 0.495483
```

Can I therefore conclude that state is actually a generator itself? Each generator/state  generates a uniform distribution of random number and different state maintain a distance such that the numbers generated do not repeat. ==> Q1

From the cuRAND guide, I learned that creating a lot of states are compute intensive. also experimented to see that. How can generate random numbers using a single `state` (variable) such that each thread consumes different random number (or the next random number is queue) from the given (single) distribution. ==> Q2

e.g. I have four threads and single state variable which generates a (hypothetical) distribution of random numbers as follows:

2 6 100 26 81 72 78 21 33 57 19 32 ...

-------- 1st Cycle ------ 2nd Cycle ------

Thread_1:  -   2   --------- 81 -
Thread_2:  -   6   --------- 72 -
Thread_3:  - 100 ------ 78 -
Thread_4:  - 26  -------- 21 -

Is this possible using a single state variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1:
`state` is data.  It represents all the data (such as seeds, sequence positions, subsequence positions, etc.) required to generate a random number.

A `generator` is a function.  It operates on an instance of `state`, and creates a random number (according to the generator type), and also updates (modifies) the `state`.

Q2:
We generate multiple states, so that multiple threads can *simultaneously* generate random numbers.  It does not make sense to talk about a single state servicing multiple threads, if the threads are generating random numbers in parallel.  Since the state is updated by the generator (see Q1) during the RNG process, you would have some threads reading from the state and other threads writing to the state, which would be a race condition, and would likely lead to corruption of the state.

What you are describing, where thread 1-4 generate 2,6,100, and 26 from a single `state` on the first cycle is not possible.

Comment: So the number of states should always be equal to the threads we launch for the kernel which is going to consume these random numbers. And thus I can say each thread operates its own distribution (uniform, normal etc).

Can I say in an application, random number generation threads should be kept separate from kernels who want to consume them. So far even in above example I took `testrand` as my kernel that consumes the generated number from `curand()`

Comment: One typical use case is to do RNG on the fly.  The random numbers produced are consumed by the thread that produced them.  No need to separate anything.  If you do up-front generation (perhaps by separate kernel) then yes, you need to be sure the numbers are generated before you consume them.